# Proper way to send data and delete rows in form react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I got a list of products and this products contain different prices. When a user selects a product he may edit all the prices. This looks like this:

```
_renderPriceRow() {
  return (
    this.props.product.prices.map((price, i) => {
      return (
        <tr key={'pricerowinput-' + Math.random()}>
          <td >
            <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={price.quantity}/>
          </td>
          <td >
            <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={price.name}/>
          </td>
          <td >
            <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={price.price}/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-sm" aria-label="Delete price" onClick={() => alert("Price deleted")}>
              <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    })
  );
}
```

I randomized the keys for the rows so the rows get rerendered as if they don't change the default values won't change if another product is selected.

Props:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const products = state.products.items;
  const isEmpty = state.products.items === undefined || state.products.items.size === 0 || state.productSelected === null;
  if(isEmpty) {
    return ( {product: null});
  }
  return {
    product: products.get(state.productSelected)
  }
};
```

So the product is taken from the store where a (filtered) list of the products lies.

For my next steps I have actually two Questions:
1. How would I add or delete a row?
2. How would I compose the prices in the table to an array and the other product fields (not shown) to an object which I can dispatch?

Due to redux everything is just a property. So getting them into the component was easy. How to get them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the values are maintained in your Redux store, you have to add and remove values by updating that store.

You can add an `onChange` handler to your table input fields:

```
<input
   type="text"
   className="form-control"
   defaultValue={price.quantity}
   onChange={this.props.store.updateField}
/>
```

where `updateField` is a Redux action that triggers a reducer to update your store.

If you want to remove the whole row, you fire an action in the button `onClick` which removes that entry from the store. You can infer which row should be removed from the event target.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. So the prodcut itself lies in a Map of like 500 and the stored objects should be immutable. Whats the proper way of  updating it? Should I make a copy of just that one product? Or should I update it in the big map which would make a copy of all the state on every update?

Comment: What also comes to me is that I only want to really store the product when the user hits save as if I update the store the overview will also get updated which is not my intent until someone hits save.

Comment: Your reducer should always return a new state (e.g. `Object.assign({}, oldState, updatedState)`) to preserve the immutability of the objects in the store. When to actually save data depends on how your overview is structured in relation to this table - you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` in the overview to display new data from the store only if there's a `dataSaved` flag, or you could store the pending updates separately in the store and use an `onSave` action to actually merge the new data into the map.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I know went with a copy of the product to another reducer which mutates it until its saved and merges it. Sounds a good way to me.